# How to draw rectangle over another rectangle in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs

I'm trying to draw a rectangle over another rectangle using mouse. What I'm stuck right now is the new `mask` rectangle doesn't get rendered. The closest thing for what I'm doing is SoundCloud where you can scrub the song.

Here's my code so far.

```
<video id="video" width="500" height="400">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" />
</video>
<canvas id="demoCanvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>



var vid = document.getElementById("video");
var frame = vid.duration * 15;

var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");

var rect = new createjs.Shape();
rect.graphics.beginFill("#000").drawRect(0, 20, frame, 100);
rect.on('mousedown', function (event) {
    var startX = event.rawX;
    $('#start').html(startX);
});

rect.on('mouseup', function (event) {
    var destX = event.rawX;
    $('#stop').html(destX);

    var startX = $('#start').html();

    var mask = new createjs.Shape();
    mask.graphics.beginFill('#FFF').drawRect(parseInt(startX), 20, destX, 100);
    stage.addChild(mask);
    stage.update();
});


stage.addChild(rect);
stage.update();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/7ewevL0t/3/

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: There is  no "mouseup" event. You can either use "click" (mouse was pressed and released on the same object), or "pressup" (mouse was pressed on the object, but released anywhere).